# How to count lst.box changes and output to lable.text in .vb?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, counting

Sorry im new :-D

i wanne do the following in a List box:

add item
add item
....

im counting the added items and display them to a label.text. and also sending that to a .txt that updates.
when all items are added i want to press a bttn "end adding Items" and then doubleclick the items to edit them(i want to count that aswell.)

So want it look like this  "changed Items / total Items"

how can i count the changes done by the doubleclick ? and how to display it ?

this is the doubleclick i did ;D

```
    Dim intIndex As Integer = lstBla.Items.IndexOf(lstBla.SelectedItem)
    Dim objInputBox As Object = InputBox("Edit", lstBla.SelectedItem)
    If Not objInputBox = Nothing Then
        lstBla.Items.Remove(lstBla.SelectedItem)
        lstBla.Items.Insert(intIndex,objInputBox)
    End If
End Sub
```

and this is the save to the lable.txt

```
Total.Text = lstBla.Items.Count
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Counter\Total.txt", Total.Text, False)
```

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: What's the problem? Take the [tour]

Comment: Add a Form level variable `Private listChangeCount As Integer` Then as a last line in your double click event `listChangeCount += 1`

Comment: i did that but now im getting 13 errors for example : no "Interger" in "string" and such

Comment: Good. Fix the errors to avoid runtime errors. Usually a `CInt()` or `.ToString` will suffice.